# Android Webview onLoad returns wrong height

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am loading a file:// url into the webview. Since my webview would need to expand/collapse, I am not using WRAP_CONTENT, but calculating the height in javascript onPageFinished event in android. But every 2 out 5 times, javascript is reporting a wrong height. For some phones, it returns a larger height, while for older low res phones it returns smaller height than the container.

I have tried to use window.onload. Just to maintain sanity on the front, I have to do a setTimeout() after 1500ms to recalculate height and resize the webview container.

Anything I am missing? How to go about fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to depend on the Android WebView, rather than inside the HTML Window

The Html Window (at JavaScript runtime execution) is 320x240 or the correct size

**If you can't get direct access to your WebView size, hold off your relevent JavaScript until the HTML Window resizes**

Example code for loading SDK video overlay, using HTML Window

```
if (!isAndroid() || isAndroidAndResized()) {
    this.translateRelativePosition(params);
    loadVideo(params.id, params.url, params);
} else {
    var relativePosition = {left: params.left, top: params.top};
    var offScreenPosition = {
        left: params.left - params.width - 2000,
        top: params.top - params.height - 2000
    }; // preload video without showing splash overlay at (0, 0)

    params.left = offScreenPosition.left;
    params.top = offScreenPosition.top;
    loadVideo(params.id, params.url, params);

    var positionCachedVideo = function () {
        if (isAndroidAndResized() || Ad.width === 320 && Ad.height === 240) {
            params.left = relativePosition.left;
            params.top = relativePosition.top;
            this.translateRelativePosition(params); // use container absolute position + video relative position (for device overlay)
            playVideo(params.id, params);
        } // make sure WebView is not 320x240 unless Ad size is 320x240
    }.bind(this);

    if (this.getWidth() !== 320 || this.getHeight() !== 240) {
        targetHtmlWindow.addEventListener('resize', positionCachedVideo);
    } else {
        setTimeout(positionCachedVideo, 50);
    }
}
```